# Change PHP form that refreshes the page to Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a simple PHP contact form on my website that I'm building. At the moment when the form is submitted the page refreshes then using PHP displays a success message underneath the cleared contact form.

Is there any way I can have the page NOT refresh and still display the PHP success message via Ajax and how can I do this?

I'm very new to PHP. Here's part of my current code...

```
if ($nr != $sum)
header('Location: index.php?msg=wrong#contactform');
else

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$Email>");


// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
header('Location: index.php?msg=sent#contactform');
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=index.php\">";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this helpful. It's a query plugin to easily make a form ajax submit. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: This is great thank you. A nice simple way to get started with it.

Answer (score 0):

On the calling page, try inserting a success message into a div
something like (using jquery)

```
.done(function(){
$('#somediv').html('Success yippy!!');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to combine two technologies. **Javascript** on the client side and **PHP** on the server side.

First you create an HTML form and success alert.

```
<span class="formSubmitted">Your form was submitted!</span>

<form>
<input type="text" id="messageInput">
<input id="submitButton" type="submit">
</form>
```

Then using jQuery(Javascript framwork), you submit this form.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url : "myphpfile.php",
      type : "POST",
      data : {
         "message" : $("#messageInput").val() 
      },
      success: function(){
          $(".formSubmitted").fadeIn();
      }
   });

});
```

And finally in the myphpfile, you can retrieve the message variable by doing this:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very much appreciated. I'm going with the plugin below for the moment but will use your code when I have more time to dissect and understand it.